# How can you separate text from a tKinter entry box into multiple elements in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, beautifulsoup

in this projecti m trying to web scrape for specfic keywords and ecport data to csv.I have created the code and it's working fine. know i m building UI for the project using tkinter.i m able to do everything except for the function "Keyword_auto(): when i enter more than 1 keyword it's not working, but it's taking it as 1 keyword. I would need your help for this. I would require help from you people.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

root= Tk()
root.geometry("640x640+0+0")
#scraping of data by passing 1 keyword at a time like helmet, horn, car cover
def keyword_auto():
    keywords_list = [keyword_list.get()]  #here keyword list should pass one by one
    keyword = 'helmets for men'
    base_url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&ie=UTF8"
    res = []
    for page in range(1,3):
        for keyword in keywords_list:
            request = requests.get(base_url + '&keywords=' + requests.utils.quote(keyword) + '&page=' + str(page), headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}) # here adding page    
               if request.status_code == 404: #added just in case of error
                  break
               soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")
               for url in soup.find_all('li', class_ = 's-result-item'):
                   res.append([url.get('data-asin'), url.get('id'), keyword])

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['Asin', 'Result', 'keyword'])    
        df.to_csv('hel.csv')

Label1= Label(root,text = "Enter keywords:", font=("arial",20,"bold")).place(x=10,y=150)

keyword_list = StringVar()

#enter keywords here seperated by comma
entry_box = Entry(root,textvariable=keyword_list,width=50,bg="lightblue").place(x=280,y=160)

#after clicking this button all keyword will pass to above function keyword_auto
button1 = Button(root,text= "Add keywords",width=10,height=2,bg="lightgreen",command=lambda : keyword_auto()).place(x=280,y=190)

root= mainloop()
```

Comment: In the UI when I enter keywords separated by commas, it's taking them as 1 string and executing the program. please someone help me with this.

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It's probably better to trim your code down to only the information that is relevant to let people review it easier. It's hard to debug when you're looking at an unorganised, uncommented wall of code

Comment: ok Ethan, in the function def keyword_auto, i want to pass 10 different keywords and i want to pass 1 keyword everytime to variable keyword. But know its taking all keywords as single keyword.

Comment: Ethan I have commented in the code where I m having a problem. please help me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your code and just pulling out what you have made reference to as not working I've made the below to help with debugging:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    print([keyword_list.get()])

keyword_list=StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=keyword_list)

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

entry_box.pack()
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

If you run this then you will see that all you are doing is taking the contents of the `Entry` box and storing them as a string in the first element of an array.

If you wanted to separate these out in to separate elements inside the array you could use a `for` loop to run through the string and separate them out into their own elements by trimming them, using a character such as "," to separate each value, but this would require instruction to the user and validation to ensure that the string is properly arranged to allow you to separate them into different elements.

Another option could be to enter a keyword, have the user submit the keyword, store the keyword as an element in an array, increment the position in the array, reload the `Entry` box and enter another value.

This could be done something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
keyword_array=[]

def command1(keyword_array, entry_box):
    keyword_array.append(keyword_list.get())
    entry_box.delete(0, "end")


def command2(keyword_array):
    print(keyword_array)

keyword_list=StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=keyword_list)

button1 = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:command1(keyword_array, entry_box))
button2 = Button(root, text="Done", command=lambda:command2(keyword_array))

entry_box.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()

mainloop()
```

Running the above will pull up an `Entry` box and two `Buttons` "OK" and "Done". If you enter a string into the `Entry` box and press "OK" this will append it to the end of the `list` `keyword_array`, then pressing the "Done" `Button` will print the contents of the `list` in the console, thus achieving what I think you're looking for.

---

Alternatively you could use `.split()` to separate based on a specific separator value, see example below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    print((keyword_list.get()).split(" "))

keyword_list=StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=keyword_list)

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

entry_box.pack()
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Using the above example if you enter "1 2 3" the console will return `['1', '2', '3']`, assuming you wanted to separate using the space character as your separator.

Comment: Ethan here is want i want, sorry i have to paste code to explain you.

Comment: I have edited code in question..please help me with this

Comment: I've explained this above, when you declare `keywords_list = [keyword_list.get()]` you are storing the value of the Entry box as a string within the first element of a list
You are taking the contents of the Entry box and placing them in the first element of the list, is that what you want to do or do you want the keywords separated out in their own elements?

Comment: so basically i want to scrape data from web and export to csv,so for that I have created UI where the end user can enter 10 keywords and it should scrape data for each keyword and save it to csv. But using above code when i enter 1 keyword it is working fine.if i enter more than 1 keyword like helmet, horn,car cover it is taking all 3 keyword as 1 keyword and giving data.I hope this explains my problem.

Comment: If you enter "helmet, horn, car cover" as it is currently then you will create a list as ['helmet, horn, car cover'], what you need to do is split them out into ['helmet,', 'horn,', 'car cover'], you can do this with any of the three methods I described above.

Comment: Add `keywords_list = []` above your `def` and then swap out `keywords_list = [keyword_list.get()]` with `keywords_list = (keyword_list.get()).split(",")` and see if that works

Comment: ethan I tried entering keywords as you suggested 'helmet,', 'horn,', 'car cover' but its still taking all 3 keywords as 1 string and pulling data.

Comment: It's not about what you enter it's about how you were storing it, have you covered the basics of Python lists, it seems you don't understand how they are stored

Comment: Thank you so much ethan it worked.You are life saver

Comment: But do you understand why it worked, please take some time to read about python lists and how strings are handled, My examples above should be able to explain it easily, you can copy and paste them in to python and run them to see what I'm talking about

Comment: Yes ethan, i will definitely go through it.thank you so much

Comment: Hi Ethan, I have one doubt, in the above code in we do scrape for one category with 10 keywords.But say we have 6 categories in the single .py file and the end user has to select the category first and then the program will go to that function and then the user has to enter keywords and program should get data in CSV. This functionality is working only when I have single category function in the single .py file. so when i add say 6 category functions in the single .py file it's taking only first keyword and executing. Hope you got what i wanted to explain you.

Comment: So I have copied and pasted the same code 6 times in the single  .py file when I select a different category, the code is accepting only first keyword.I think there is some issue with looping

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of Stack Overflow, this question has been answered, if you have further difficulties then raise a new quesion